# How to ADD a role to a user by Services

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to update a user by Services module. Currently a user has UID=2 and a role ROLE1. I am trying to add ROLE2 to this user also, so that this user will have two roles: ROLE1 and ROLE2.

When I use PUT to this endpoint: user/2
with data:
  $data = array();
  $data['roles'] = array( 5 => 'ROLE2');
  $path = 'user/2';

The role of the user is updated to ROLE2 only.

Question is: how to keep ROLE1 while adding another role to that user?

Comment: What's the role id number for Role 1 and 2? From your Question, it looks like `5` is the ID for Role 2. If for example `4` is the ID for Role 1, then try sending this with the `PUT`: `$data['roles'] = array(4 => 'ROLE1', 5 => 'ROLE2')`. FYI, only privileged users can grant extra roles to a user's account via Services.

Comment: thank you Tyler, but do I have to send all roles together even if the user has previously have one? So the only way would be first to GET the user's existing roles, add them to array with the new one and then POST?

Comment: Yes, that is probably true. I'll typically use the System Connect resource when the app starts, that way the user's current roles are delivered to the app upon start up. Otherwise you can build a custom Service Resource to add a role to an existing user.